# AOSPA Building lib errors

Tags: android, github, build, rom

hello guys i am try to build aospa for me device Oneplus3 but i got the following error

ninja: error: 'out/target/product/oneplus3/obj_arm/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libqc-skia_intermediates/libqc-skia.a', needed by 'out/target/product/oneplus3/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libskia_intermediates/LINKED/libskia.so', missing and no known rule to make it
build/core/ninja.mk:151: the rule for the target„ninja_wrapper“  missed
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] error1

Answer (score 0):

If you run the `breakfast` command, follow along here:

First, run repo sync --force-broken, make sure that you DON'T have anything in the .repo/local_manifests and let that one finish. Then, since the OnePlusOne is quite the supported device, run `breakfast <codename>` and let that finish, it will download all the sources for you and create a roomservice.xml in .repo/local_manifests. I believe it will also overwrite the current device tree with the one existing in device// with the latest official sources. Then, you can either use the export command to tell jack how much ram it is going to use, and then just run make -j bacon. You'll get the output in out/target/product I believe.

If you run the `Brunch` command, follow along here:

Run breakfast to get the sources, then run brunch

If you run the `Lunch` command, follow along here:

Run breakfast to get the sources, then lunch _-userdebug
ie. lunch lineage_ks01ltexx-userdebug.

There are more than just userdebug, but it is the best for finding bugs etc. A thread on XDA explains this better than me, which you can check out [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/chef-central/android/eng-vs-userdebug-performance-ram-usage-t3082108)

Or you  know, you can just google.